# Styling buttons image only works on last item

Tags: wpf

I have a style

```
<Style x:Key="HomeButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="32"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="/Images/HOME.png"></Image>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and I have some xaml in a control

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource HomeButtonStyle}" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource HomeButtonStyle}" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource HomeButtonStyle}" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource HomeButtonStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

However the image is only shown in the last button.

My questions are why? and how to make the image show in all the buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your style you should set `ContentTemplate` instead of `Content` directly.

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
  <Setter.Value>
     <DataTemplate>
       <Image Source="/Images/HOME.png"></Image>
     </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: What are the other implications of this? It feels more like a workaround - honest question really. I kind of prefer the other answer atm but don't want to miss something out of ignorance.

Comment: This is a better answer. You should use ContentTemplate because Visual tree will be recreated each time, also note that data templates are lazy loaded when needed. My solution is a bit hacky but it's the only way if you want to set the same element of visual tree as a content of other controls multiple times. On the other hand, content template can be reused as much as you like.

Answer (score 4):

```
<Image x:Key="HomeImage" x:Shared="false" Source="/Images/Home.jpg" />
<Style x:Key="HomeButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="32"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource HomeImage}" />
</Style>
```

Your code is reusing Image control which was already added to another visual tree. Use x:shared to create a new instance of Image control each time and all will be fine. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx).